# I want to the time difference. The time format is HH:MM:SS

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting an error **NaN**. My code looks like this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var startTime = moment('8:73:18', 'HH:mm:ss')
var endTime = moment('10:73:18', 'HH:mm:ss')
var secondsDiff = moment(endTime).diff(startTime, 'seconds')

console.log(secondsDiff)
```

Comment: That's not even proper time... You can't have `73` minutes.. Change to `53` for both and you'll see that the output is `7200`. (Flagging as **a simple typographical error**)

Comment: BTW, you can change your code to `var secondsDiff = endTime.diff(startTime, 'seconds')` and get the same result (no need to run `moment` again).